# Oracle SQL Pivot with Rollup group by

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot, dynamic-pivot

I would like to know if it's possible to do a rollup group by with a PIVOT XML?
The result i want is something like this.

```
NAME        | CITY 1 | CITY 2 | CITY 3 | CITY 4
Jone Do     |   0    | 2      | 0      | 4
Joe Blo     |   2    | 0      | 2      | 2
STATE 1     |   2    | 2      | 2      | 6
Jackson     |   0    | 2      | 0      | 0
STATE 2     |   0    | 2      | 0      | 0
```

Right now i have tryed to do the group by after the pivot but it's now working correctly, the merge all STATE 1 together so it's only display STATE 1 with result and STATE 2 with result.

EDIT -----
This is the query i've tryed

```
select people.fullname, people.statename, cit.city
from people
left join citylist cit on people.id_city = cit.id_city
pivot xml(
  count(city) for city in ( select city from citylist )
)
group by people.fullname,
rollup(people.statename),
cit.city
```

PS. the City pivot result on xml i know, but i translate all to html after.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please share the query that you used for generating this data. This can be easily achieved with conditional aggregation.

Comment: What does the input data look like? And, why XML? Why doesn't standard PIVOT work for your problem?

Comment: @Popeye i've edited the main post, the query looks like this sample.

Comment: @mathguy i've edited my post, i use PIVOT XML because the IN Clause are dynamic.

Comment: You can use PL/SQL in order to get dynamic pivot without `PIVOT XML`. Check out [these sample questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dynamic-pivot+oracle) prior to yours(total 12 results are listed)

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan that's true we can do that, but it's more easy to convert the result in html with xmlattributes, xmlelements and xmlserialize inside a <table> tag.